# Modelling complex django model relations efficiently

Tags: django, database, django-models, modeling

I am programming a django website for oragnizing events where I need to be able to store information about which attendees will stay for meals. I have currently got it working in a way which I think is really not optimal, and I would like to improve it. I would be glad to hear any ideas about how *you* would go about it.

## What I need

So, for each **event** (which can have a duration of a variable number of days) I need to be able to display what I call a **meals table**. This table will hold information about each day's meals. Each **day** has three **meals** (breakfast, lunch and dinner). Each meal needs to contain information about the number of people that are staying for that meal plus the dish that each of those people are going to have from the **menu**. The menu also contains a variable number of **dishes** that can be modified by the administrator of that event (the menu is the same for every meal).

So, the general concept diagram would be something like this:

```
Event
|_ Meal Table
    |_ Day 1
        |_ Breakfast
            \_ Dish 1 -> Nº of people
            \_ Dish 2 -> Nº of people
            \_ Dish n -> Nº of people
            ...
        |_ Lunch
            \_ Dish 1 -> Nº of people
            \_ Dish 2 -> Nº of people
            \_ Dish n -> Nº of people
            ...
        |_ Dinner
            \_ Dish 1 -> Nº of people
            \_ Dish 2 -> Nº of people
            \_ Dish n -> Nº of people
            ...
    |_ Day 2
    |_ Day n
    ...
```

So, for each **meal** of each **day** of each **event** I need to store how many people have chosen each one of the available **dishes**, taking into account that one person cannot choose more than one dish in each meal.

## My solution so far

The (very inefficient) way I have done this so far is:

1. I created the following models:

   - `Dish`:

     ```py
     from django.db import models

     class Dish(models.Model):
         name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)

         def __str__(self):
             return self.nombre  

         def get_default(self):
             return Dish.objects.get(id=1)

         def get_default_id(self):
             return self.get_default().id
     ```
   - `Day`:

     ```py
     import auto_prefetch
     from django.db import models

     class Day(auto_prefetch.Model):
         event = auto_prefetch.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
         person = auto_prefetch.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
         date = models.DateField('Date')

         breakfast = auto_prefetch.ForeignKey(
             Dish, 
             null=True, blank=True, default=Dish.get_default_id, 
             on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
             related_name='breakfast'
         )
         lunch = auto_prefetch.ForeignKey(
             Dish,
             null=True, blank=True, default=Dish.get_default_id, 
             on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
             related_name='lunch'
         )
         dinner = auto_prefetch.ForeignKey(
             Dish,
             null=True, blank=True, default=Dish.get_default_id, 
             on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,
             related_name='dinner'
         )
     ```
   - `Event`: This model has many methods and properties, but amongst them there is a function called `get_meal_table` which returns all the `Day` objects belonging to this event. For example, whenever I want to know, for a specific day of an event, how many people are having a specific dish for lunch, I use this `get_meal_table` method to obtain all `Day` objets of the event and I then filter that queryset to find the `Day` objects with the desired `date` and `lunch` properties.
   - `Person`: It represents the attendees.

The problem with doing it this way is that the number of model objects that are needed to represent the complete data about an event increases with both the number of days that the event lasts and the number of its attendees. Therefore:

- If the duration of the event changes at some point, I need to create extra `Day` objects for every single person that is already attending the event. This is very inefficient, because if we are extending for 10 days the duration of an event with 100 attendees, we need to create no less than 1000 new `Day` objects.
- If there is a very long event (like one month), for every new attendee we need to create about 30 new `Day` objects.

I would like to find a solution to represent the same data but in a more 'scalable' way so that the number of objects does not increase so much with the number of days and the number of attendees.

## Another idea

I thought of another possible way of doing this, but I don't know if it would improve things much. The diagram would be:

```
Event
\_ Meal Table
    \_ Day 1
        \_ Dish 1
        \_ People for breakfast: Person 1, Person 2
        \_ People for lunch: Person 1, Person 2
        \_ People for dinner: Person 1, Person 2
    \_ Day 1 
        \_ Dish 2
        \_ People for breakfast: Person 3
        \_ People for lunch: Person 3
        \_ People for dinner: Person 3
    \_ Day 1 
        \_ Dish n
        \_ People for breakfast: Person 4, Person 5
        \_ People for lunch: Person 4, Person 5
        \_ People for dinner: Person 4, Person 5
    ...
    \_ Day 2 
        \_ Dish 1
        \_ People for breakfast: Person 1
        \_ People for lunch: Person 1
        \_ People for dinner: Person 1
    \_ Day 2 
        \_ Dish 2
        \_ People for breakfast: Person 2
        \_ People for lunch: Person 2
        \_ People for dinner: Person 2
    \_ Day 2 
        \_ Dish n
        \_ People for breakfast: Person 3, Person 4, Person 5
        \_ People for lunch: Person 3, Person 4, Person 5
        \_ People for dinner: Person 3, Person 4, Person 5
    ...
    \_ Day n 
        \_ Dish 1
        \_ People for breakfast: Person 1
        \_ People for lunch: Person 1
        \_ People for dinner: Person 1
    \_ Day n 
        \_ Dish 2
        \_ People for breakfast: Person 2, Person 5
        \_ People for lunch: Person 2, Person 5
        \_ People for dinner: Person 2, Person 5
    \_ Day n 
        \_ Dish n
        \_ People for breakfast: Person 3, Person 4
        \_ People for lunch: Person 3, Person 4
        \_ People for dinner: Person 3, Person 4
    ...
```

Basically, it would involve only [image] objects in order to represent the full data, so the dependency on the number of attendees is removed. Each event has, for each `Day` and for each `Dish`, one object with a many to many relationship to `Person`.

I have not tested this yet, but the code could be something like this:

```py
from django.db import models
import auto_prefetch

class Day(auto_prefetch.Model):
    event = auto_prefetch.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField('Date')
    dish = auto_prefetch.ForeignKey(
        Dish, 
        null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    breakfast = models.ManyToManyField(
        Persona, blank=True, related_name="breakfast")

    lunch = models.ManyToManyField(
        Persona, blank=True, related_name="lunch")

    dinner = models.ManyToManyField(
        Persona, blank=True, related_name="dinner")
```

With similar `Person`, `Event` and `Dish` models from before.

The problem I see with this method is that I would need to find a way of avoiding that a `Person` be for example in two `breakfast` attributes from two differen `Day` objects of different `dish` but same `date`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem statement is

> So, for each meal of each day of each event I need to store how many people have chosen each one of the available dishes, taking into account that one person cannot choose more than one dish in each meal.

then I'd go with the basic models

- `Event` - an event, as you have.
- `Dish` - a dish available at the event, as you have.
- `Person` - an attendee of an event, as you have.
- `EventDay` - a single day of the event, containing the physical `date` (and other info as required)

and for meal selections, simply

```
class MealSelection(models.Model):
    day = models.ForeignKey('EventDay')
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person')
    meal = models.CharField()  # could add choices breakfast/lunch/dinner, or make this an FK
    dish = models.ForeignKey('Dish')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [('day', 'person', 'meal')]
```

The `unique_together` statement will prohibit, on the database level, anyone from choosing multiple dishes per meal per day per event.

Then, to query the counts, you could just

```
dish_counts = dict(  # make dict out of tuples
    MealSelection.objects.filter(event=..., day=...)
        .values('dish')  # group by dish
        .annotate(n=Count('*'))  # select group counts
        .values_list('dish', 'n')  # select dish/n as tuple
    )
```

and you'd get a dict mapping Dish IDs to their counts.

Yes, you'd have up to N_DAYS * N_ATTENDEES * N_MEALs of `MealSelection`s, but SQL databases are *very* efficient at dealing with that.